# Magento2 Correct Sequence to flush all Caches/Static files

Tags: magento2, cache, code-generation

I'm having a hard time in development with generated classes, pre-processed files and caches in Magento2.

In comparisson with Magento1 it seems no longer possible to efficiently develop when disabling all caches, plus I also need to see if caches interfere with features I build.

My problem is, that there are so many caches and generated files, I'm not sure which are dependent of each other and in what sequence I should flush them in order to get a fresh view of all my developments.

There's the Backend Cache area

- All the standard caches that can be cleaned
- The Catalog image cache
- The Static Files cache
- The CSS/JS Cache

Then there is the bash commands

- php bin/magento cache:clean
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Then there folders you can manually delete

- var/generation
- var/cache
- var/page_cache
- var/view_preprocessed
- pub/static

That's a lot of possibilities and probably not all. So if I deploy a large update, Code Changes, CSS/JS changes, Template changes

Which of these steps should I do to get everything cleaned? In what sequence must these steps be done?

Comment: You can write a command to delete the files which target multiple files to delete and use `cache:flush` command to clear the cache.

Comment: What is the difference between "clean" and "flush"?

Comment: You can refer this link https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun/issues/588

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Normaly you don't have to clear the folder manually.
I use the following "rotation"

### For **clearing** the cache:

- bin/magento cache:clean

### For **reindex** new xml files:

- bin/magento index:reindex
- List item
- bin/magento cache:clean

### For **refresh** or insert **new plugins**:

- bin/magento setup:upgrade
- -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE
- bin/magento index:reindex
- bin/magento cache:clean

### If you need a "**full-cleanup/refresh**":

- bin/magento setup:upgrade
- -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:di:compile
- -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE
- bin/magento index:reindex
- bin/magento cache:clean

Answer (score 0):

`php bin/magento cache:clean` - If you change .phtml files code and cache enable from admin then you have to use of it.

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` - If you change CSS, JS or .html files code then you have to use of it. These files are located in web folder.

`Var folder delete manually` - If you change Block, Controller, Model etc **.PHP** file code then you have to delete manually first **var** folder.

Use of these commands you can see your change.

Comment: - php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
Seems to require me to click the "Flush Static Files Cache" Button, otherwise I wait for about 5min for the generation and it still doesn't work

When changing Plugins or Depency Injection on PHP Classes, it seems to me that it only works when I flush the directory var/generation

Comment: When changing Plugins or Depency Injection on PHP Classes, you have delete var folder.

Comment: When changing Plugins or Depency Injection on PHP Classes, you have to run "php bin/magento setup:di:compile" only